# Adding a two second delay into background music

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, appcelerator

This is the code that I have written to play a music in the background. how can I add a two-second delay into it? this would give time for the images to fully load

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Animate</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google 
Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
        if(!isChrome){
  $('#iframeAudio').remove()
}
else{
 $('#playAudio').remove() //just to make sure that it will not have 2x audio 
in the background 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="Happy Birthday Song.mp3" allow="autoplay" style="display:none" id="iframeAudio">
</iframe> 
<audio autoplay loop  id="playAudio">
  <source src="Happy Birthday Song.mp3">
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not you use **onload** event. It will fire after all images, scripts and CSS loaded.
In onload function fired then you can play music.

Comment: please give me an example. I do not know javascript. got this all from the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi here is what I suggest you should do. First and foremost remove the autoplay attribute on the audio tag.

then you can use javascript or jquery to control when the audio plays. In your case you wants the audio to play when all assets are loaded..so here is an example..

```
//javascript
 window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementbyId("playAudio").play();
 }
 //jquery
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#my_audio").get(0).play();
 });
```

if for any reason you still want some more delay let say 2seconds.. you can extend this further...

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById("playAudio");
//javascript
window.onload = function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
       myAudio.play();
   }, 2000);
 }

 //jquery

 $(document).ready(function() {
     setTimeout(function(){
       $("#my_audio").get(0).play();
     }, 2000);    
 });
```

PS. Use any of the two. I remember you said you're not familiar when JS. Best of luck pal

Comment: it worked. thank you. but I would like to add another 2-second delay.

Comment: then you can use setTimeout.  You can change it to something like this..    
var audio = document.getElementById("playAudio");

 window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    audio.play();
  }, 2000);
 }

Comment: @user264498 check for the update.. I edited the answer for your taste..

Comment: Sorry to say but the delay is not working. I was creating a webpage for my girl. its almost midnight now. if you reply within 45 minutes i might get it working otherwise this is where it ends.

Comment: audio tag doesn't seem to be working in google chrome. have to sue iframe.

Comment: @user264498 so sorry I got your message 7 hours later. let me know what the issue is in details if there's any need. Sorry man once again.

Comment: No worries. I found a solution online and in time. She liked it very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with. The following script adds a 3-second

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.setTimeout(function () {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('my_audio');
    iframe.setAttribute('src', 'Happy Birthday Song.mp3');
}, 3000); 
</script>
```

'my_audio' is the iframe id.

```
<iframe style="display:none" id="my_audio">
</iframe>
```

for your own music

```
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'your music here');
```